# I'm having trouble finding this matrix $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ and the standard basis $\mathcal E$ for $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This was a homework assignment, but unfortunately it was the last homework assignment of the semester so I never got feedback and I'm just reviewing it for a final. I'm supposed to let $\mathcal B=\{\mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2, \mathbf b_3\}$ be a basis for a vector space $V$ and let $T:V\to \mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation with the property that $$T(x_1\mathbf b_1+x_2\mathbf b_2+x_3\mathbf b_3)=\left[\begin{matrix}2x_1-3x_2+x_3\\-2x_1+5x_3\end{matrix}\right]$$ I think I need to find $T(\mathbf e_1)=\left[\begin{matrix}2\\-2\end{matrix}\right]$ and then find $T(\mathbf e_2)$ and $T(\mathbf e_3)$ by the same method. Then how would I find $\left[T(\mathbf e_1)\right]_\mathcal E$, etc.?

Comment: It seems to me that $[T(\vec{b}_1)] = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$, not $T(\vec{e}_1)$.  Thus, you've computed $[T(\vec{b}_1)]_{\mathcal{E}}$, because the usual coordinates for a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are with respect to the standard basis.

Comment: So then if I calculated $\left[T(\vec{b_1})\right]_\mathcal E$, then my matrix $_\mathcal E \left[T\right]_\mathcal B=\left[\begin{matrix}2&-3&1\\-2&0&5\end{matrix}\right]$?

Comment: Yep, that looks right to me.